# Reminder on voting to migrate

Tags: discussion

> #1 rule to consider after determining a question may be a better fit
> elsewhere:
>
> ### Don't migrate crap.
>
> [meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/178209)

In going through the close queue, I ***often*** see questions voted to migrate, but the question *needs improvement*. This should be done **before** we migrate it, otherwise we've just decided it's a bad question for us and then sent a bad question to another site, which they then need to vote to close.

There's no reminder of the "no crap" rule when selecting to migrate, but it's something that we need to be better about. For those who don't have it, here are some stats:

[image]

So it's not just SU that has rejected migrations, but I think it's something we should be able to improve on. I bring this up because I know a lot of close-voters do frequent meta and may want to take a little bit more time to scrutinize a question in the close queue to determine whether it's a *good question* in the first place.

One other thing that some may not be aware of - migration results in a post score resetting to zero. Maybe use this as a guide.

Comment: For me personally a question has yo already not be crap for me to even vote to migrate it; I often see attempts to migrate low quality stuff; which makes me a sad panda

Comment: If it's not appropriate for your Stack, how can you tell if it's crap or not? Wouldn't it be more appropriate (and more fitting the SE theme) to have the EXPERTS determine if it's crap and how to shine that turd?

Comment: @Smithers *Be familiar with the destination site. If you have never even visited the destination site before, read through the FAQ thoroughly and make sure the question actually belongs there. Don't look at the name of a site and automatically assume the question can be asked there. Each site has its own rules, and rules vary greatly across sites.* [source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work/10250#10250) We can only migrate to **meta SU, SO, Serverfault, Webapps and Android**. This is because of the overlap in knowledge.

Comment: For those of us without a clue about java script, for instance - when flagging something that's clearly 'about coding' would you prefer a close flag or a migrate flag? Further examination of the depth of lustre on the turd scale would not be possible in such circumstance, as the reviewer 'doesn't understand the question'.

Comment: Having just read through the first link - I'll just skip them in future, I guess.