# Why is this question on SQL migrated?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I've asked a question about SQL, not asking for a piece of code per se, but more of a general advice.

I hesitated between Stack Overflow and Super User, tried a search on the topic, found thousands of questions on SQL and VBA (some with piece of code) on Super User, and it seemed a nice fit. Four people voted it to migrate it in minutes, without explanation.

How is it that questions on VBA, which is a programming language OK here, but not on SQL, which is not a programming language per se? What's the line between Stack Overflow and Super User?

Question: *https://superuser.com/questions/929237/are-not-equal-join-a-standard-use?noredirect=1#comment1258588_929237*

Comment: Because VBA questions are specifically on topic and SQL questions are not?

Comment: @ramhound your comment is not helping.

Comment: I disagree.  VBA questions are specifically referenced in the help center as being on topic.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my rationale for voting to migrate your question:

This was a programming question. It was not about using a particular database management system or software. As such, it was not on topic here and belonged on Stack Overflow instead.

As for the difference between your question and VBA questions, the key difference is that VBA does not exist in isolation. It is a language that is necessarily tied to Microsoft Office software, questions about which are within the scope of Super User. As stated above, your question was purely about SQL syntax, not about using software. Hence, it wasn't a very good fit for Super User.

There is precedence for VBA questions being migrated to Stack Overflow, too. When a question is purely about syntax, or, for lack of better description, about programmer-level issues (as opposed to user-level issues), it can be migrated to SO.

For what it's worth, having a question migrated isn't a bad thing. If anything, your question will have a better audience on Stack Overflow. That was my motivation for migrating -- to improve your chances of getting a useful answer.

More reading about related topics:
[Inconsistent Mod response to migrating Excel questions between Stack OverFlow & Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/q/4565/76571)
[Are detailed Excel VBA questions best posed here or on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/7076/76571)
[Reminder on voting to migrate](https://meta.superuser.com/q/9110/76571)

Comment: T-SQL is also specific to a program (sql server) it does not exist in isolation event though you can use it on differnet platforms. Like , in VBA you can access...an sql database, for example. SQL is not really a programming language: if you put on your CV "programmer" because you know sql , you'd probably be laughed at. 10 years ago, you could be a superuser just because you knew how to record a macro. Now, sql is part of "dabbling" in computer. Bottom line, 4 people choose to migrate the question. Even though I disagree, thanks for taking the time to explain your rationale.