# Are T-SQL questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've read *[Why is this question on SQL migrated?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9449/why-is-this-question-on-sql-migrated)*, but sadly the upvoted answer has only two upvotes... I'm asking a similar question, but I am looking for something more definitive.

There is some confusion about the name of the database and the language. Many refer to T-SQL as SQL for example, and as such, the SQL tag (I feel) needs to be made more explicit as to its meaning.

Can someone confirm that the following two points are off-topic on Super User (IMO they are)?

1. The syntax (maybe the syntax is not legal/returning an error)
2. A query is not returning an expected value(s)

So no question about the database itself, just about the language/use of language

If so, should we update the SQL tags to reflect this? This question made me ask as the tags are not as clear as they could be IMO *[How to include when a clause in MySQL is within 'where'](https://superuser.com/questions/1122583/how-to-include-when-clause-in-mysql-within-where)*

Comment: I agree that they are off-topic. Maybe the tag reference should should point people to DBA.SE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are *very* few situations where the average home user is going to be working with SQL, and to a significant extent, many questions on DBs are going to be off-topic.

I'd consider language questions and questions on queries to be off-topic here. If I saw either sort of question you've mentioned I'd close it.

I'm not entirely sure what sort of [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)/T-SQL and other SQL flavours would be *on-topic* here though. I suppose they would be questions to do with installation, running and other *end user* issues.

Comment: If that's the case, thanks for clarification and I'll leave the tag alone :)

Comment: For on topic SQL: most likely SQLite as some end-user software uses it as datastore, one prominent example being Skype. See here: http://superuser.com/questions/1053383/how-to-eleminate-duplicate-contact-lists-in-skype-and-prevent-duplicates or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201575/how-to-retrieve-messages-relative-to-a-whole-skype-conversation-from-sqlite-main

Comment: "I suppose they would be questions to do with installation, running and other end user issues." I was about to write an answer that said the same... why is that written at the bottom? :(