# Can we have the option to request approval when making edits

Tags: feature-request

When we gain rep, we no longer require approval when we make an edit.

However, I feel there should be the option to request approval, (although it's probably only useful for tags).

I've just asked this [Are T-SQL questions on topic?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11800/are-t-sql-questions-on-topic) for this very reason. If there was an option for me to edit the tag, but check the box for "request approval before saving to live" then I would have done that as it would give me more confidence that the edit I make is valid.

I guess it can then just go into the normal review queue

Comment: There would have to be a rep exemption I think.

Comment: I meant a rep gain exemption.

Comment: If you want to edit a tag and are unsure, then the best thing to to is to ask a meta.su question and tag it [tag:discussion].

Comment: MSE equivalent: [Could I optionally get my edit approved?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103270/295684)

Comment: I did already with another question but that's a discussion and can lead to ambiguity...  The queue is either approved or not!

Answer (score -2):

I like the idea of getting approval/feedback from the community when in doubt over the usefulness of a certain edit. However, if the Super User *Suggested Edits* review queue is anything like the one on Stack Overflow, many reviewers work their way quickly through the review queue and don’t pay much attention to the usefulness of the edit (presumably to accumulate another badge).

I sometimes see useful edits being rejected with no other feed-back other than the stock “no improvement whatsoever” reason and on the other hand, I see bad edits being blindly approved.  (I have less than 2k reputation here, but on Stack Overflow and Unix & Linux, I usually check the question or answer of the suggested edit in its original context to make a useful judgement.)

Personally, when I’m unsure about a certain course of action, I’d prefer to get qualitative feedback (e.g., reasons for/against) so I can use that information to make a better judgement in future similar cases, but with the Review queue, a particular edit is often often either approved or rejected without any useful feedback.

I’d agree with David Postil that more useful feedback would be gained from the community by posting on Meta. There may be ambiguity over the results of the discussion, but at the very least, you’ll become aware of consequences or other factors that you might not have considered and can make a more informed decision.

To clarify, I’m not against this proposal (I would’ve downvoted if that were the case) as I can understand some users might want a simple yes/no as to whether an edit is useful or not. It’s just a feature I’d be unlikely to use.

Comment: Good post, but I disagree that the queue isn't the right thing to do because of what you described. Although I agree with what you've described - the queue isn't a perfect system at all - but, it **is** the system which is in place and if it's good enough to review post edits then it's surely good enough for tag edits?! Yes, asking on Meta is a nice way to proceed but... maybe tag edits should be approved by users with a certain reputation? Whilst not a guarentee, there is usually a link between rep and desire to help

Comment: @Dave It's already the case that editing tags requires more reputation. You only need 2k to edit questions/answers but 5k for tags - https://superuser.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits I've yet to gain 5k on any SE site so I don't know if reviewers pay more attention when reviewing tag edits (though I have received decent feedback when my own tag edits were being approved).

Comment: This suggestion sadly also makes it more difficult for me/us. It means writing the post, reading responses, potentially replying, making decisions etc. Very long winded compared to clicking an option for a review