# Should autoplay be updated

Tags: discussion

[autoplay](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/autoplay) currently shows the following description

> Automatically running programs from inserted discs, USB flash drives, etc.

This suggests that something physical has to start. However, auto play could be for other reasons.

This question was tagged with [autoplay](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/autoplay). [On a Mac, how do I get rid of Disable HTML5 Autoplay plugin?](https://superuser.com/questions/1236061/on-a-mac-how-do-i-get-rid-of-disable-html5-autoplay-plugin)

Obviously the trigger for auto-play is when the web page loads (or similar).

Due to the current description of [autoplay](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/autoplay), I removed it from the post.

As I don't like [editing the tags without verification](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11801/can-we-have-the-option-to-request-approval-when-making-edits) first, can you please vote on one of my 2 answers below (or post your own).

Comment: I'm not going to vote for either as I am feeling ambivalent.

Comment: I guess not voting is also voting for leaving it as is :) @DavidPostill

Comment: I suppose so :)

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as [autoplay](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/autoplay) needs some other tag to define what exactly is auto-playing it kind of feels like it is a meta tag and should be replaced by more specific tags.

The [autoplay](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/autoplay) tag should be removed completely.

Comment: Hmm. Are you suggesting we have auto-play-video, auto-play-audio ... instead?

Comment: Probably not. If your problem is with a program not auto playing then tag with that program. Tags should narrow down a specific problem with a specific thing, not give vague hints and descriptions. The tag edit reject reason of (quote from memory) "tags edits should help to narrow and define a question, not simply show what it contains" feels appropriate here.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'd suggest `Windows-autoplay` for launching discs or usb programs, and similar `product-action` tags for other situations. That would keep it specific and descriptive rather than relying on vaguely linked tags to describe an overall problem.

Answer (score 0):

[autoplay](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/autoplay) should remain as is only be used when something physical has happened, such as inserting a CD, USB key etc

Answer (score -2):

[autoplay](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/autoplay) should be updated to include when ever something starts to play automatically and is not limited to something physical such as CD/USB to begin the progress. It should be updated to include things such as loading a program or a web page etc

Comment: I can see [tag:autoplay] being used for vids/audio, but I don't think it should apply to programs (maybe [tag:auto-start] for those?)

Comment: @DavidPostill, what about audio... and as such, audio which plays when a web page has loaded :)

Comment: Yeah, classify with vids. vids are just pictures with audio :)

Comment: And, of course vids/audio should have some other appropriate tags to distinguish them from auto-play usb or whatever ...